# C# library Binance.NET: get current average coin price

Tags: c#, .net, cryptoapi, cryptocurrency, binance

I am using [Binance.NET](https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net) library. It's a wrapper for [binance.com api](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/#change-log). I want to get the current average price of the Bitcoin.
It seems that the library has no method to do it. Yes, it allows to use [tickers](https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net/tree/6d4bd20cd13a6277a5a1961f1fbd88355cd108dc/Binance.Net/SocketSubClients), but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: What do mean about `average price of the Bitcoin`?
If you want to receive the last price use [this method](https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net/blob/6d4bd20cd13a6277a5a1961f1fbd88355cd108dc/Binance.Net/SocketSubClients/BinanceSocketClientSpot.cs#L241)

Comment: @OlehHrechukh yes, I am talking about last price. But I want to get it without using tickers. Is it real with this API or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OlehHrechukh proposed to use `SubscribeToSymbolMiniTickerUpdatesAsync` method. This method allows to subscribe to updates: when a trade happens we get an update. In another words, we subscribe to **trades**. But if we want to get the price of a symbol we can use [this method](https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net/blob/6d4bd20cd13a6277a5a1961f1fbd88355cd108dc/Binance.Net/Interfaces/SubClients/Spot/IBinanceClientSpotMarket.cs#L127).